# How to create ListView with item to add items

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am new on xaml, vb.net and coding. I'm trying to make an app with ListView.
I know how to use ListView but I want another kind of ListView: a ListView with one item which allow us to add an item.

I don't know how do that. Maybe UserControl?

I attached a sketch for better understanding.

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to go about this. Basically, it all comes down to using some `Event` to trigger the creation of a new item. One option is to make the last item a `Button` and handle the `Click` event. In the event handler, you would have code to insert an item one place before the last item in the list.

Comment: Ok i will try that option. 
But what about saving the listview.
I'am using an observableCollection normally. If i have a "button-item" in my listview how could i save it ?
Wait i just need to populate that collection with my data and not with items right ?

Comment: You would need to add some kind of extra item to the end of your ObservableCollection, and then have your DataTemplate recognize it and show the Button instead of the normal template. When you save, just save all the items except the last one.